# How to use previous version of libraries for old version of React.js, how to avoid peer dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, npm, version, libraries, compatibility

Just wanted to know, because we sometimes we have to use older version of React. Could somebody please provide a simple solution to my problem.

Comment: What is this `console.log()` thing here? Made no sense what you had there...

Comment: Also, you seem to have a habit of putting all your own text to quotes in your questions. Please stop that, use it only for something that is not the question text written by you.

Comment: @JamesZ : I tried not to put there something but without that I was not able to ask my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either specify the peer dependencies in package.json, or lookup the peer dependencies based on the react version and then running

> npm install [package-name]@[version-number]

for example, if I need to install an old version of prisma, say prisma version 3.2.0, I would have to run the following command in-console:

> npm install prisma@3.2.0

Comment: Thank you @Ruler !! Suppose I am using react 16 for my project and I want to use any package from MUI which has a peer dependency of React 17 or React 18, So do I have to specify react 17 again in the package.json file ?

Comment: You wouldn't have to, but you would have to find an older version of MUI that supports React 16, that is the best way to avoid any dependency conflicts.

Comment: this will overwrite current package, not add new package with other version